# Add Video Source with PHP URL

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a video site using PHP, and I want to insert video source code from a PHP URL.

For example, if I want to get Episode 1 from PHP, I want it like this:

```
example.com/player.php?=episode1
```

For Episode 2:

```
example.com/player.php?=episode2
```

I don't understand how to link all of the source pages with the main index page.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it: Use a form on your homepage (`index.html`?) to select which video you want, and send it to `player.php` using a GET method. Then use the following on `player.php`:

```
<?php
    $select = $_GET['select']; //This will be the number input for the video number
    echo("<video><source src="episode$select.mp4"></video>"); //This will source the video named `episodeX.mp4`, where `X` is the select value from the form on `index.html`.
 ?>
```

Just ask if you need any additional clarification.

Comment: I will use this player.php page to embed on my main website and source is also from embedding sites. I dont want my homepage to be used

Here is an example what I'm trying to do:- https://gokumania.com/e/player/player.php?v=aHR0cHM6Ly92ay5jb20vZG9jMjIxMDg5MTkwXzQ3MjU4OTk4OA==